# Too many connection error in mysql - Nodejs & Mysql?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database

I am using **nodejs-v9.2.0** and **mysql** in my application.

#### Error:

code: 'ER_CON_COUNT_ERROR'

errno: 1040

#### NPM Modules:

1. [Mysql](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql)
2. [Mysql wrapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql-wrapper)

#### Code:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var pool = mysql.createPool({
   canRetry: true,
   database: "dbname",
   host: "host",
   user: "user",
   password: "password",
   connectionLimit: 100,
   supportBigNumbers: true,
   bigNumberStrings: true,
   charset: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
   multipleStatements: true,
   debug: true
   waitForConnections: true,
   queueLimit: 0
});

pool.on('connection', (connection) => {
   connection.on('error', (err) => {
     connection.release();
   });

   connection.on('close', (err) => {
     console.error(new Date(), 'MySQL close', err);
   });
});

var createMySQLWrap = require('mysql-wrap');
var sql = createMySQLWrap(pool);
```

#### Note:

I have noticed an [open issue](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/889) in the mysql npm github.

**Any work around to solve this issue?**

Any suggestion will be grateful

Comment: Hi, Increase maximum connections limit in mysql server `set global max_connections = 200;`

Answer (score 0):

You can check this using

```
show variables like 'max_connection%';
```

The output will show something like:

| Variable_name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| max_connections | 151 |

You can change this simply by issuing following:

```
SET GLOBAL max_connections = your_desired_value;
```

Or you can also change this in your MySQL config file.
You need to add:

```
max_connections = your_desired_value
```

You need to locate your `my.cnf` file.
There is a `[mysqld]` section in the configuration file, just add this at the end of the file and restart your MySQL server.

```
# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
user = mysql
port=3306
socket      = /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock
skip-external-locking
key_buffer = 32M
max_allowed_packet = 64M
table_open_cache = 64
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
max_connections=your_desired_value
```

The effect should take place immediately.